# How to access Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item Property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, dictionary

I am new to the C#/.Net and have a problem with class Dictionary. I created a dictionary of groups and added an item (or more items, now it doesn't matter):

```
Dictionary<int, ListViewGroup> groups = new Dictionary<int, ListViewGroup>();
groups.Add(1, new ListViewGroup("Group1"));
```

I would like to find my group by its key. In documentation it says that there is an Item property which I can access directly or by indexer. However, when I try to access it directly:

```
ListViewGroup g = groups.Item(1);
```

my compiler says that there is no definition for property Item in Dictionary class.
Can anyone explain this to me please?
Thank you.

Comment: Pro-tip: When you type the dot `.` and intellisense shows up; all of the methods, variables, properties, events, etc. you can access are going to be in that list. It's a great way to find the method you're looking for, even if you don't know how it's called.

Comment: @Nolonar: Not always true: by default, intellisense options "hide advanced members," which means you don't get everything.

Comment: @DanPuzey I see. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) is an indexer, you can verify it by looking at definition:

```
public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

Simply use indexer syntax to access elements by key:

```
ListViewGroup g = groups[1]; 
Console.WriteLine (g.Header); //prints Group1
```

Note: this will throw `KeyNotFoundException` if no entry with such key would be present in `groups` dictionary. For example `groups[2]` will throw an exception in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groups[n]`.

If you look at [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item`, you may find:

> This property provides the ability to access a specific element **in the collection** by using the following C# syntax: **myCollection[key]**.

Or search the web for "C# indexers":

> [Indexers Tutorial (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(v=vs.71).aspx):
>
> Defining an indexer allows you to create classes that act like "virtual arrays." **Instances of that class** can be accessed using the **[]** array access operator.

Indexers, or `Item` in this case, are never directly accessed.

Comment: You mean groups.Item[n]? Because this has the same problem.

Comment: @Wolf no it hasn't. It really helps if you show the exact code and the exact compilation error in your question.

Comment: Using `Item` as the dictionary name in your answer is highly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because there is no property called Item in the dictionary class on the base level.

```
Dictionary<int, ListViewGroup> groups = new Dictionary<int, ListViewGroup>();
groups.Add(1, new ListViewGroup("Group1"));
```

<strike>ListViewGroup g = groups.Item(1);</strike>

```
ListViewGroup g = groups[1];
```

From a practical understanding point of view(what I am about to say is only for basic understanding) the dictionary is essentially an array but instead of being forced to use numbers in order you can use any number you like or even a string.

```
new Dictionary<int, ListViewGroup>
```

In your dictionary you have

```
1    Group1
```

groups[1] will retrieve Group1.

To really understand the coolness of the Dictionary is when you use a string key.

```
new Dictionary<string, ListViewGroup>
```

so that if you did this

```
groups.Add("mykey1", new ListViewGroup("Group1"));
```

groups["mykey1"] will retrieve Group1